# AWS CloudFront returns http 307 when origin is S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have created the s3 bucket with some files. I created the CloudFront distribution with that S3 bucket as origin and it changed status to deployed.

When I curl CloudFront for any file I get:

```
<Error><Code>TemporaryRedirect</Code><Message>Please re-send this request to the specified temporary endpoint. Continue to use the original request endpoint for future requests.</Message><Bucket>MY-BUCKET</Bucket><Endpoint>MY-BUCKET.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com</Endpoint><RequestId>...</RequestId><HostId>...</HostId></Error>
```

When I curl my S3 bucket for any file I get that file contents.

What am I doing wrong? How to force cloudfront to cache files so that clients don't need to get data from S3 directly?

Comment: Did you try the Curl right away when you got the deployed message ?

Comment: @error2007s more than 3 hours it is deployed, but the message still persists

Comment: What region is your bucket in? What is your bucket endpoint that you've specified in your CloudFront distribution?

Comment: Try invalidating your CloudFront distribution. It's possible that the DNS S3 issue may be resolved, but the response has been cached by CloudFront. Or wait for the TTL to expire before retrying.

Comment: global endpoints are deprecated so please a regional one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65142577/is-cloudfront-origin-using-s3-global-domain-name-performing-better-than-regional

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Thx Matt Houser from comment to my first post!

It seems CloudFront cached my first requests to files when distribution wasn't fully ready (but it was in deployed state at that time, so beware!). I requested invalidation to all files which were in cache, it took some minutes, but after invalidation was done, all files were curled with http 200 using CloudFront url.

The problem became clear after the comment from Michael-sqlbot:

> All buckets have at least two REST endpoint hostnames. In eu-west-1,
>   they are example-bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com and
>   example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com. The first one will be immediately
>   valid when the bucket is created. The second one -- sometimes referred
>   to as the "global endpoint" -- which is the one CloudFront uses --
>   will not, unless the bucket is in us-east-1. Over a period of seconds
>   to minutes, variable by location and other factors, it becomes
>   globally accessible as well. Before that, the 307 redirect is
>   returned. Hence, the bucket was not ready.

Comment: Actually, it wasn't the *distribution* that wasn't fully ready.  If it hadn't been ready, it wouldn't have been working.  [It was the *bucket* that wasn't ready](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Redirects.html).  Temporary redirects are normal for the first few minutes of a new bucket's life, sometimes a little longer, when the bucket isn't in the us-east-1 region, because of the way the global endpoint DNS works.  Responses served from cache by CloudFront also have an `Age:` header, which would have suggested that what you were seeing was cached.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot what do you mean under the bucket was not ready? It was curled normally and cloudfront not at the same time.

Comment: All buckets have at least two REST endpoint hostnames.  In eu-west-1, they are example-bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com and example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com.  The first one will be immedately valid when the bucket is created.  The second one -- sometimes referred to as the "global endpoint" -- which is the one CloudFront uses -- will not,  unless the bucket is in us-east-1.  Over a period of seconds to minutes, variable by location and other factors, it becomes globally accesible as well.  Before that, the 307 redirect is returned.  Hence, the bucket was not ready.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thx for information! Now I better understand the problem.

Comment: Another piece of info, my s3 bucket is in Ohio, took about 45 minutes for the DNS to propagate and not get the 307 from cloudfront.

Comment: Or 24 freakin hours for ap-southeast-2 (Sydney)!

Comment: Had same error, found this and it worked, thanks! Also did a bit more googling and found this one that is pretty much spot on and official, should be mentioned here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-http-307-response/

Comment: Although this seems to describe my situation exactly, the resolutions described here do not work for me. Both my S3 bucket and my REST endpoint are us-west-2. I am seeing a 307, followed by multiple 301's before the browser throws its hands up and says "I give up, too many redirects".

Comment: Is it a problem to use the first (*non-global*) endpoint in general? `example-bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 20):

Just to clarify a bit more if it happens to you, there's a few choices:

- Either wait [up to 24h](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-http-307-response) for the changes to propagate fully.
- Change your bucket location to the `us-east-1` region.
- But the easiest is probably to switch your CloudFront origin domain name from `<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com` to `<bucket>.s3-<region>.amazonaws.com`

Go to your Distribution settings -> Origins and Origin Groups and edit the current origin

For example, with a bucket named stackoverflow in the `us-west-2` region, it would become

```
stackoverflow.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Changing the bucket location to include the region fixed things for me, many thanks!

Comment: Worked!  IMPORTANT: Still needed to wait like 2 minutes and do cmd+shift+r to make sure Chrome doesn't cache the image request.  Thanks. :)

Comment: Not working for me. Getting 307, followed by multiple 301s. Both my bucket and CF origin are (and have always been) in us-west-2.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the CloudFront origin domain name from .s3.amazonaws.com to .s3-.amazonaws.com worked for me!

you can get this from the RegionalDomainName attribute.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-s3-bucket.html