# Is CloudFront origin using S3 global domain name performing better than regional one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution that has S3 in `eu-west-1` as origin.

I know that S3 regional domain name `{bucket-name}.s3.{region}.amazonaws.com` give me instant initial CloudFront initialisation without downtime. Global `{bucket-name}.s3.amazonaws.com` needs 2~3 hours to be initialized (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58423033/1480391).

Does CloudFront perform the same with **regional** or **global** S3 domain name?

Is **regional** S3 domain name slower than **global** S3 domain name regarding how CloudFront fetches S3 origin (internal DNS domain resolution for example)?

Comment: There is no different regional or global. Because CloudFront server content from cache based on nearest your location. Its not serving from S3.

Comment: @aviboy2006 I'm talking about performance regarding CloudFront fetching S3

Comment: No it will not be. Because once content is cached no issue whether is global or regional.

Comment: I know CloudFront is caching S3.. it's a CDN. But that's not the point, please read the question

Comment: Anyway. Looks like global endpoint is deprecated and new AWS region created avec 2019 will only have regional endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Global endpoint is deprecated

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html

The global endpoint is called "legacy". That means the new way is to systematically use the regional endpoint.

Also the regional endpoint performs better. To simplify, when using the global (legacy) S3 URL format:

1. Requests the global S3 endpoint.
2. It asks what the regional S3 endpoint is.
3. Redirects you to the regional S3 endpoint.
4. Requests the regional S3 endpoint.

When you use the regional (modern) S3 URL format:

1. Requests the regional S3 endpoint.

All credits to [this reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/k6j2cu/s3_global_vs_regional_domain_name_as_cloudfront/gep0orv/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)